# debug the environment used by make and port gcc from source

Tags: gcc, makefile, grep, porting, abi

I know how to build `gcc` from source, what I still have to figure out is what are the exact environmental variables used by `gcc` when configure and building `gcc` itself, I'm actually trying to build the compiler from source using another version of `gcc` with different ABI.

Any idea on how to get this kind of information beside "try to `grep` all the variable that starts with `$` inside all `makefile`s and configuration files" ?

Answer (score 0):

You can see a list of [Environment Variables Affecting GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Environment-Variables.html).

To create a completly independent gcc with a new toolset, have a look at [LFS](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/view/stable/), they explain how to build gcc from an existing OS for a future OS.

There is also a page about [building gcc](http://gcc.gnu.org/install/build.html), which talks about `BOOT_CFLAGS='-O'` and `CFLAGS_FOR_TARGET` and `STAGE1_TFLAGS` and `BUILD_CONFIG`. There is also some additional variables for cross-compiling and ada compiler.

Comment: are you sure that it's what I'm asking, I already visited that page, it's about `gcc` usage at runtime and it's not about how to compile `gcc`. Please confirm.

Comment: You compile gcc with gcc, no ? Then it does also apply. I added additional information.

Comment: nope, my point is how to compile `gcc` correctly, I don't care about _how to use_ `gcc`, only what happens when building `gcc`.

Comment: Yes but gcc env variables interfere in gcc building too, so that may be a hint. For me gcc builds correctly out of the box, just follow up the howto on their website, or LFS guide to create an ABI independent version.

Comment: The "building gcc" env vars are relevant, the ones at the first link are not